# Basics of Batch Jobs and Email Scheduler

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, batch-processing

I am creating a system which will highlight the **percentage of students who have cleared the test**.

Until pass, Student need to retake the test. Students are categorized based on Departments. The table has the list of students records, (no of attempts, name, id, dept).

Under each department we have HODs. Email notifications will be send to respective HODs with the list of students (fail) asking him/her to follow up with students for retaking the test. This will be schedule for once in every week of March.

***What I have created is***.

A system where HR on selecting department, will display all students (pass and fail) with no of attempts and their respective HODs.
On selecting Fail Radio, the dashboard will display all list of students who will retake the test.
HR can then send email to the respective HOD with the list of Fail students.

**Note:**
There is an Active Directory (AD) which has the records and from where I can pull all the latest details of the test based on student ID.

**PROBLEM NOW**
The problem with this is HR has to select Department one by one and send mail.
I have a list of 50 departments and therefore the new requirement is to make this AUTOMATED.

And now I am confused on how to achieve this. I have heard about batch jobs, bat file. But I do not know what is to be done to make this automated i.e. on the month of march, once in every week, records will be pulled from AD in the morning and in the evening, mail notifications will be send to the respective department HODs with the list of their students who need to retake the test.

I am using C#, SSMS.
*Your kind assistance in this regard will highly be appreciated.*

Comment: Giving a massive explanation is probably fine, but you need to post the parts of the code you're having issues with and present the problems you are having with it and expected results. Right now it is impossible to see what you have done and what can be done to fix your problem.

Comment: That is why I will suggest you to read until the end before commenting. This will definitely help you to understand the question better.

Comment: There are so many ways to achieve this that this question becomes completely open-ended. You could use Task Scheduler to run a batch, a Powershell script, or a custom program, you could build a timer into your project, you could write a separate service to do this. And all of these are big projects completely out of scope for [so]. Without a specific piece of code you are having trouble with, this basically amounts to "please write an entire program for me"

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you Charlie for your reply. What I was thinking of creating a task scheduler and trigger a bat file. The bat file will further call a stored procedure A. The Stored procedure A will loop through all department admins and call Stored Procedure B one by one. The stored Procedure B is for sending email using SSML. Will this strategy work??

Comment: Yes it would, but personally I would create a SQL Server Agent job instead

Comment: I would surely look into both task scheduler and SQL Server Agent Job for making it work. I really appreciate your time. Thank you so much.